# Reference llvm-3.6/llvm as llvm

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I've installed llvm-3.6-dev package on Willy (Ubuntu 15.10). The package works fine except for one tiny problem - all the headers and libs are in `/usr/include/llvm-3.6`, e.g. `/usr/include/llvm-3.6/llvm/IR/Support.h`. This means that my program which references just `llvm/IR/Support.h` doesn't build against these packages.

Is there a way I can tell G++ or Ubuntu to look inside this folder by default?

Currently, I am simply adding the include paths to the command line directly. However this is going to break horribly if, for example, the package were to decide to place them in `/usr/local/include` instead of `/usr/include`, so it's pretty fragile.

Can I just pass some extra argument to `apt-get install` to get it to install them without a prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add `-I path` to your g++ command-line options, and `-L path` to the linker command. However, LLVM does provide a tool for producing the options required to build with a particular version of LLVM (as long as LLVM itself is built with the correct options)

To use that the `llvm` library functions and headers, you should use `llvm-config --libs`, `llvm-config --ldflags` and `--llvm-config --cxxflags` to get "right" options to build your code.

This should go into your makefile or whatever you use to build your code.

An example using that:
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/Makefile

by the way, building your own LLVM [and Clang] isn't terribly hard - it takes a little while, around 15 minutes on a desktop with a 6-core AMD processor, a bit more on my quad-core laptop, and a fair bit less on my machine at work)

This is how I build clang + llvm:

Check out llvm to by:

```
cd sources     # Or whatever you want to keep your LLVM sources.
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git llvm
```

Then create a temporary "buildllvm" directory:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ../llvm
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

Adjust the number 8 to be around the same as you have processor cores.

This doesn't specify a destination directory, so will install itself in /usr/local/{lib,include,...}

I also build a debug version of the libraries:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++ 
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/llvm-debug -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ../llvm
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

which does specify the install directory.

Comment: I've installed llvm-3.6-dev, but I don't have an llvm-config program

Comment: Ah, but I do have llvm-config-3.6.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the Makefile you've linked to still hardcodes the location of llvm-config. I have llvm-config-3.6 in my path, but the shell doesn't seem to want to handle it from my script :(

Comment: Yes, I hard-code the llvm-config directory, because I want to be able to build either debug or release build of llvm, and they live in different places. If you set your $path to have the directory of llvm-config [and create a sumbolic link for llvm-config to link to llvm-config-3.6 ], it should work. But I build my own LLVM + Clang, as I just described above. It's not very hard, and it gives you more freedom where you install things, and of course, the option to choose whichever version of llvm you like to use.

Comment: I can build my own LLVM easily. Doing so for Travis however is not so easy and it's detracting contributors from my project that it's a complete bitch to build because you have to build LLVM first which takes quite some time.